# I want to ask you how it should look this code to C++

Tags: php, c++

I want to ask you how it should look this code to C++:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $array[$i]="test".$i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in C-based languages, arrays normally start at zero, so looping through an array of 10 elements would be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) array[i] = i;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would look something like this (a complete program).

```
/* required headers */
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>

/* code has to be inside a function; main is the start-point of the program */
int main() {
  std::map<int, int> array;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    array[i] = i;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use a map above, since PHP "arrays" are actually like maps in other languages (although completely mimicing their behaviour in a statically-typed language is a hassle). Of course, since the program does little, you could save yourself some typing and not type something that effectively does nothing.

**EDIT:**

```
/* required headers */
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

/* code has to be inside a function; main is the start-point of the program */
int main() {
  std::map<int, std::string> array;
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << "test" << i;
    array[i] = stream.str();
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** based on your edits

Important addition to the other answers that php doesn't require:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main
{
   using namespace std;
   string array[11]; // tell the compiler array is an array of size 11
                     // this array starts at index 0 and goes up to 10
                     // totaling 11 elements
   for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++){  // you might want to start at 0 here
      ostringstream strStream
      strStream << "test" << i;
      array[i] = strStream.str();
   }
   return 0;
}

// accessing array outside the bounds you told the compiler
// results in undefined behavior, practically this means crash
// or data corruption
```

This is the most direct conversion. However, you probably wish to look into [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) in @eq-'s answer for general associative containers where you don't care if the index space is contiguous and just general safety. C style arrays are considered a code smell these days.

Comment: I'm sry <?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $array[$i]="test".$i;
}
?>

Comment: ostringstream is pretty much the canonical solution for this kind of problem. There's a couple others (lookup itoa), but ostringstream will be the safest. There's boost::lexical_cast, but thats just wraps a stringstream.

Comment: OK, thank you very much . :) I have problem with the library #include <stringstream>. I use GNU g++ 4.4.4 .

Comment: @rammstein, sorry about that. I fixed the include.

Answer (score -1):

```
for ( int i=1; i<=10; i++){
   array[i] = i;
}
```